# Как отследить загрузку popup окна, которое было открыто через window.open()?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть web-страница что-то типо парсера. Она очень простая: всего лишь textarea и две кнопки. В textarea записываются некоторые номера из которых потом, при нажатии на одну из кнопок формируются ссылки. Далее эти ссылки вставляются во внутрь window.open() и открывается соответствующее окно, а уже из этого окна, с помощью расширения tampermonkey (расширение, которое позволяет запускать пользовательские скрипты на сайтах) собираются нужные данные и отправляются в бд.
Код открытия страниц:

```js
let popup;
const openPage = (i) => {
  let iter = i;
  const links = createlinks(); // получится массив ссылок
  if(iter === links.length){
    window.open('./excel.php');
  }
  if(iter >= links.length){
    return;
  }
  
  let waitPage = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    popup = window.open(links[iter]);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      iter++;
      resolve(iter);
    }, 5000);
  });
  
  waitPage.then(res => {
    popup.close();
    openPage(iter); // Рекурсия, так как номеров в textarea лежит много
  });
}
```

Как видно из кода, новая страница открывается каждые пять секунд. Но проблема в том, что эта новая страница не всегда успевает загрузиться за эти секунды, следовательно tampermonkey не запускает свой скрипт и данные не парсятся. Я пробовал вешать на popup событие onload но почему, то обрабатывался только один номер, а дальше рекурсия сбрасывалась. Пробовал делать popup.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'), результат тот же самый. Вопрос - как можно реализовать эту логику,

Comment: У тебя в `openPage` `iter` всегда равен 0...

Comment: Ошибся, там let iter = i;

Comment: Так ты и принимай тот `iter` сразу как параметр... `openPage = iter => {...}`

Comment: А я что делаю, Iter улетает в функцию как параметр openPage(iter) передаётся

Comment: Ты делаешь лишнее присвоение. ;)

Comment: Смотри, вот есть вопрос на тему "как отследить загрузку дочернего окна" https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.a7dde743-649ac758-2e95b2b7-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/1132537/how-can-i-check-to-see-if-a-child-browser-window-has-finished-loading Может там найдется ответ, который тебя устроит...

Comment: А, да это я для удобства. Оно вообще погоды не меняет, нужно чтобы новое окно загружалось, а уже потом выполнялся setTimeout.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже пробовал методы описанные там. К сожалению не помогает :(

Comment: Событие `load` можно навешивать только на окна "из одного источника"...

Comment: Да, я это уже понял. Получается я ни как не смогу заставить скрипт дождаться загрузки всей страницы окна.

Comment: Есть еще `postMessage()`... Но если сама страница не настроена на ответы другим "ресурсам" - узнать что-либо о ней клиентским скриптом с другого ресурса не получится..

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответы